# On Windows, where's the location of the pg_service.conf file?

Tags: qgis, postgresql

Trying to install QGIS for a few people but they have Windows. The documentation says to save it on the home folder on Mac but completely forgets about the Windows.

File is needed in order to open the project.

Where to put this file?

Comment: with 'PC' I assume you mean 'Windows'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this doc page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) for a reference of all possible system variables used by PostgreSQL (it´s hidden in the *libpq* pages...a little sneaky).

Now, if I remember the old Windows *CMD* correctly, you can just set that variable to the directory of your choice, e.g. (`Windows + R | cmd`):

```
setx PGSYSCONFDIR "<path_to_dir>"
```

and put that file there.

Comment: We could improve this answer saying that the pg_service.conf need UNIX LineEnds (LF) and is saved as pg_service.conf on windows.